# Recipients in EXM count is always 0

Tags: solr, xconnect, exm

I tried to use EXM in siteore and I uploaded CSV file I already got message that was "Contacts expected to be imported are 2" but "Recipients" are still 0 like in attached Images so I can't complete process of sending email.
**Note**.

it worked before but I don't know what is the problem now??.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Which Sitecore version you use? Are those 2 contacts in global opt out list maybe?

Comment: @Marek Musielak I use sitecore version 9.1.i tried to upload external csv file not filled from list manager